# Laravel Join query eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have three models like following:

```
class Category extends Eloquent
{
protected $primaryKey = 'categoryID';
public $timestamps = false;


protected $fillable = [
    'categoryName',

];

public function categoriesfields()
{
    return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\Categoriesfield::class, 'categoryID');
}
}
```

Categoriesfield:

```
class Categoriesfield extends Eloquent
{
protected $primaryKey = 'fieldID';
public $timestamps = false;

protected $casts = [

    'categoryID' => 'int'
];

protected $fillable = [
    'fieldName_ar',
    'categoryID'
];

public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\Category::class, 'categoryID');
}

public function categoriesoptions()
{
    return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\Categoriesoption::class, 'fieldID');
}
}
```

Categoriesoption:

```
class Categoriesoption extends Eloquent
{
protected $primaryKey = 'optionID';
public $timestamps = false;

protected $casts = [
    'optionParent' => 'int',
    'fieldID' => 'int'
];

protected $fillable = [
    'fieldID'
];

public function categoriesfield()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\Categoriesfield::class, 'fieldID');
}
}
```

when I run this query I got this error :

```
$data= Category::with('category.categoriesfields')-
>with('category.categoriesfields.categoriesoptions')
            ->where('fieldID', '=', 3)->get();
```

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'fieldID' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `categories` where `fieldID` = 3)
Any help please to know what is the problem !!?

Comment: $data= Category::with('category.categoriesfields')-
>with('category.categoriesfield.categoriesoptions')
            ->where('fieldID', '=', 3)->get(); try this

Comment: The same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Constraining Eager Loads](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads) for this purpose:

```
$fieldID = 3; // added the variable here to see how to import it to the closure

$data = Category::with([
    'categoriesfields' => function ($query) use ($fieldID) {
         $query->with('categoriesoptions')->where('fieldID', '=', $fieldID);
    }
])->get();
```

It happends because the where clause is added on the categories table which does not have the `fieldID` column.

Comment: I used your solution but I got this:
Call to undefined relationship [category] on model [App\Models\Category].

Comment: Check it now.. you must remove the `category.` prefix

Comment: Did you removed the category. prefix from relationships?

Comment: Updated again, please try it again

Comment: working, but I retrieve also feildID=4 and fieldID=5 ??